# Geometry/triangle problem determining leg-length

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have been struggling with this problem, and I think it should be possible to solve but right now I cannot find how.

[image]

Given two coordinates/points **(x1,y1)** and **(x2,y2)**, the angle formed by legs d1 and d2 is **90°**.

What are the lengths of **d1** and **d2**?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> The slope of the line passing through the segment **$d_1$** is
>   $$\tan(a).$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

applying Pythagorean theorem in right triangle with legs $d_1$ & $d_2$, $$d_1^2+d_2^2=(\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2})^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2\tag 1$$ 
$$\sin a=\frac{d_2}{d_1}\implies d_2=d_1\sin a$$

consider right triangle with legs $d_1$ & angle $a$.  The other leg is $d_1\tan a$ & hypotenuse $d_1\sec a$

The horizontal distance between the points $(x_1, y_1)$ & $(x_2, y_2)$ is given as $$x_2-x_1=d_1\sec a+(y_1-y_2)\tan a$$
$$d_1=\frac{x_2-x_1-(y_1-y_2)\tan a}{\sec a}=\color{blue}{x_2-x_1-(y_1-y_2)\sin a}$$
Now, substitute the value of $d_1$ in (1) to find $d_2$.