# Coordinates change movement problem

Tags: coordinate-systems, angle

yesterday I asked a related question that was a specific case of my problem. It was solved here: [Geometry/triangle problem determining leg-length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640445/geometry-triangles-problem)  but I would want to know if its possible to get a generic universal solution for the problem.

Given the next situation:

[Problem scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykW0m.png)

We have the typical 2D coordinate system, axis **x,y**. Every point in the problem is defined using this reference  (i.e  (x1,y1), (x2,y2),  (x3, y3))

We have a particle in  that can move only using his own x,y axis (in red). We know the angle **a** between his x red movement axis and the x blue reference system. This angle could range from 0 to 360. (So axis can be aligned or inverted)

The problem would be to find a generic solution to know how much the particle should move in his red x,y axis to be placed in a given new coordinate.  (i.e move from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) or to (x3,y3).. The destination points can be placed anywhere.

Any solution or guide on how to work with this would be appreciated

Comment: You seem to left all answers unnoticed in your previous question.

Comment: Hi @Kaster I noticed them and I upvoted them but it seems that I have not enough reputation and my upvote won't appear. Also I could not find how to mark the answer as solved. If you can indicate me the way I would be really glad to do it. Thanks